# Force FlatList to re-render after sorting data

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a jobs app. In my JobsComponent, where I display the jobs, I have added a sort option that allows users to sort the list of jobs by different criteria. The flow is this: 1) I get the jobs from the server -> 2) the user sorts the jobs -> 3) the sorted list of jobs is re-rendered on the screen.

The problem is that step 3) is not working. The actual list of jobs *is* being sorted (I can see that in the logs), but my FlatList is not being re-rendered.

**What I have tried**

1. I have a flag, sortOrderChanged, set in my state. Whenever the user selects a sorting option, I change this flag in my componentDidMount() method:

```
this.setState({
                sortOrderChanged: !this.state.sortOrderChanged,
                selectedSortOrder: dataFromChild
            });
```

and pass it to FlatList as extraData:

```
<FlatList 
                    data={sort_array}
                    extraData={props.sortOrderChanged}
                    renderItem={renderJobItem}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                    style={{marginTop: 10}}
                    />
```

This does not help though. I have also tried sending the whole state to the FlatList and passing it to extraData, but it also didn't work. I assume the problem is that my data is not actually being changed, but sorted. However, I do not know how to force it to re-render. Can someone help me out, please?

Below is my JobsComponent.js:

```
function RenderJobs(props) {
    var json = JSON.parse(props.jobsData);
    var sort_array = [];
    for (var _id in json) {
        sort_array.push({
            _id:_id,
            jobtitle: json[_id].jobtitle,
            company: json[_id].company,
            duration_driving_value:json[_id].duration_driving.value,
            duration_transit_value: json[_id].duration_transit.value,
            duration_walking_value: json[_id].duration_walking.value,
            duration_driving:json[_id].duration_driving.text,
            duration_transit:json[_id].duration_transit.text,
            duration_walking:json[_id].duration_walking.text,
            date: json[_id].date,
            formatedDescription: json[_id].formatedDescription,
            applyUrl: json[_id].applyUrl
        });
    }
    //sort the list based on user selection
    if (props.sortOrder === props.sortArray[0]) {
        sort_array.sort(function(x,y){return new Date(y.date) - new Date(x.date)});
    }
    else if (props.sortOrder === props.sortArray[1]) {
        sort_array.sort(function(x,y){return x.duration_driving_value - y.duration_driving_value});
    }
    else if (props.sortOrder === props.sortArray[2]) {
        sort_array.sort(function(x,y){return x.duration_transit_value - y.duration_transit_value});
    }
    else {
        sort_array.sort(function(x,y){return x.duration_walking_value - y.duration_walking_value});
    }


    const renderJobItem = ({item}) => {
        var  durationCarApi, durationPublicTransportApi, durationWalkApi, formattedApiDate, formattedJobDescription;
        //format data
        return (
            <Panel //custom component used to display each job
                jobTitle={item.jobtitle}
                company={item.company}
                durationCar={durationCarApi}
                durationTram={durationPublicTransportApi}
                durationWalking={durationWalkApi}
                dateAdded={formattedApiDate}
                onPress={() => 
                    {
                    props.navigation.navigate('JobDetails', {
                        jobTitle: item.jobtitle,
                        company: item.company,
                        durationCar: durationCarApi,
                        durationTram: durationPublicTransportApi,
                        durationWalking: durationWalkApi,
                        jobDescription: formattedJobDescription,
                        applyUrl: item.applyUrl
                })
                    }
                }/>
        );
    }

    //handle loading/error scenarios
        return (
            <FlatList 
                    data={sort_array}
                    extraData={props.sortOrderChanged}
                    renderItem={renderJobItem}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                    style={{marginTop: 10}}
                    />
        );

}

class Jobs extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            jobTitle: this.props.navigation.getParam('jobTitle', ''),
            address: this.props.navigation.getParam('address', 'error'),
            sortOrderChanged: false,
            sortArray: [0,1,2,3],
            selectedSortOrder: 1 //default is sort_driving
         };
      }

    componentDidMount() {

        handleSorting = (dataFromChild) => {
            console.log('Sort order clicked: ' + dataFromChild);
            this.RBSheet.close();
            this.setState({
                sortOrderChanged: !this.state.sortOrderChanged,
                selectedSortOrder: dataFromChild
            });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.bkg}>
                <RenderJobs 
                    jobsData={JSON.stringify(this.props.jobs.jobs)}
                    isLoading={this.props.jobs.isLoading}
                    errMess={this.props.jobs.errMess}
                    navigation={this.props.navigation}
                    sortOrder={this.state.selectedSortOrder}
                    sortArray={this.state.sortArray}
                    sortOrderChanged={this.state.sortOrderChanged} 
                    />
                <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
                    <RBSheet //custom component used to render the sorting options
                        ref={ref => {this.RBSheet = ref;}}
                        height={200}
                        duration={250}
                        customStyles={{
                            container: {
                            justifyContent: "center",
                            alignItems: "center"
                        }
                    }}>
                    <SortSheet //this is the child component used to render the sorting options
                        sortOrder={this.handleSorting}
                        sortArray={this.state.sortArray}/>
                    </RBSheet>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: you are not changing any state or anything while sorting, you can just sorting the array and the array is sorted in the memory, but react doesn't know it as there is no state change, try to have a local state

Comment: @SarmadShah, do you mean keeping my jobs data in my state, then passing that state to extraData? If so, I'll try to do that and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Move your data from **local variable** to **state**.
Or add **forceUpdate** after `else`.

Comment: I moved my jobs data to state as follows:

In my JobsComponent, I changed my state to contain the jobs data
`this.state = { 
            jobs: JSON.stringify(this.props.jobs.jobs),
         }`

I passed the state to the component that includes the FlatList (`<RenderJobs sortOrderProps={this.state} />)` and passed sortOrderProps to extraData. `<FlatList extraData={props.sortOrderProps}/> But it still doesn't refresh the list. :( Is there smth I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the keyExtractor to item._id:

```
<FlatList 
                    data={props.jobsData}
                    extraData={props.sortOrderProps}
                    renderItem={renderJobItem}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item._id}
                    style={{marginTop: 10}}
                    />
```